# SQL Server catch error from extended stored procedure

Tags: c++, sql-server, c, stored-procedures, error-handling

Hello I have an extended stored procedure that sends an error message.

```
srv_sendmsg(pSrvProc, SRV_MSG_ERROR, errorNum, SRV_FATAL_SERVER, 1,
            NULL, 0, (DBUSMALLINT) __LINE__, 
            buff,
            SRV_NULLTERM);
```

I've set the severity to SVR_FATAL_SERVER just as a test to see if I can cause the message to throw an exception in the sql.

In my SQL i'm doing:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC dbo.xp_somethingCool
    SET @Error = @@ERROR
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'AN Error occoured!'
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
          ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

I would think that when my xp sends the error message the tsql would catch the error and select the error_number and error_message. Instead what ends up happening is that the xp sends the message and the T-SQL continues on its way like nothing happened. The @@Error variable doesn't get set either.

So I was wondering if there was any trick to getting SQL to catch an error from an XP ?

Thanks,
Raul

Comment: Microsoft recommends that you do not use `srv_sendmsg` anymore.  See the warning on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164673.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only test the result from an extended stored proc, and use that to throw an exception.

```
...
EXEC @rtn = dbo.xp_somethingCool
IF @rtn <> 0
    RAISERROR ...
...
```

In *very* simple terms, an extended stored proc is not SQL run by the database engine so you can't issue RAISERROR. See [KB 190987](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190987) for some more info

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx) to throw an exception.

Per comment:  Are you not creating your own extended stored proc?  If so, you can use throw or do something like 1/0 to throw an exception.

Comment: The question is how can i RAISERROR inside an extended stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

Never raise anything so high. Anything raised with severity above 16 will abort the batch, so your T-SQL catch block never gets a chance to run. Something as high as SVR_FATAL_SERVER  will shutdown the server immedeatly.

Comment: I don't disagree, but when its raised from an xp it seems to be ignored which is the reason I did it. I wanted to see if it actually did anything. I don't know if there's another api call i can use to cause sql server to actually process the message, or if i'm missing a flag ?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but it may be that the severity is capped for your own protection. Try using 16 for your test.